# How to show favourites (different components) on dashboard page? Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have a page with charts like a report which contains a lot of different custom charts (different components) and there is a possibility to add each one to the favorites in order to show them on a Dashboard page. 
On the Dashboard page I receive an array of ids and need to render all required components. So the question is how it's better to do?

Currently I'm importing all components from the report module and adding them to entryComponents of Dashboard module and then with help of *ngIf showing them based on the array of ids. It looks a bit difficult and requires a lot of additional code.

I would appreciate any simpler suggestions to solve this task. Thanks!

Comment: With approach that you specified, you do not need to add them to **entryComponents** array

Comment: You are right, it's my mistake in the description.

Comment: I will provide my answer shortly

Comment: I'm using ComponentFactoryResolver.

Comment: Why do you need *ngIf then?

Comment: Sorry about that. I don't need *ngIf anymore

Comment: I'm adding charts to the  <ng-template favorite-charts-host></ng-template>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to look into **dynamic components**, in a nutshell:

1. You need to create a map `componentsMap: ([id: number]: Type)`. **Where Type - component type**, in that way you will have correlation between ids and component types, and you can store only ids.
2. Create a placeholder and get reference to this placeholders using `@ViewChild('ref') vcRef: ViewContainerRef;`
3. After that just push every component dynamically by id (you can use `componentsMap` to get `Type`) to the `ViewContainerRef` like

   ```
   let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
   let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
   ```

   where `component` it's every component type from saved ids.

---

As i understood from comments you've done something similar to that (in question you said that you use *ngIf though), so hope that can help, at least some parts of it.

Comment: Just to clarify. If I have more than 15 component types and I need them in the EntryComponents. How do you think it is okay to import all of them in the Dashboard module?

Comment: you can create **an array variable** somewhere (in another file, for example) like `const dynamicComponents = [Component1, Component2, etc]` and afterwards **spread them into declarations and entryComponents** like `declarations: [...dynamicComponents, AnotherComponent], entryComponents: [...dynamicComponents]`

Comment: Exactly what I need! Thanks!